# Merging two sets and adding source flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two sets of models. I want to merge them and display them *intermixed* in a single list but I want to be able to flag each record and tweak the display of each row based on which set it came from.

```
@first_set = Model.where(...)
@second_set = Model.where(...)
```

and the HTML output I am looking for would be a table like below. `Property1` and `Property2` are part of `Model` but `Source` is not.

```
Property1  | Property2  | Source
-------------------------------------
foo        | bar        | first_set
rawr       | grrr       | second_set
cat        | dog        | first_set
```

If this was pure SQL, I would so something like this:

```
SELECT Property1, Property2, 'first_set' ... UNION ALL SELECT Property1, Property2, 'second_set' ...
```

How can I merge these two sets to easily produce my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reach for an OO solution for this particular case. I'll use `Post` as a placeholder model and `Published` as the condition distinguishing the two sets here to help with cognitive load:

```
class DecoratedPost
  attr_reader :post

  def initialize(post)
    @post = post
  end

  def self.decorate(posts)
    Array(posts).map { |post| new(post) }
  end

  def published?
    raise 'Not implemented!'
  end   
end

class PublishedPost < DecoratedPost
  def published?
    true
  end
end

class UnpublishedPost < DecoratedPost
  def published?
    false
  end
end

@published_posts = PublishedPost.decorate(@posts_a)
@unpublished_posts = UnpublishedPost.decorate(@posts_b)
@all_posts = @published_posts + @unpublished_posts

# views/index.html.erb
<% @all_posts.each do |decorator| %>
  <%= decorator.post.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Good answer. I hadn't thought about it like this.

Comment: One critique of this, I think I would have `DecoratedPost` inherit from `Post` so the ActiveRelation could be maintained as opposed to having to convert to an array in the `decorate` method. I would have to test it out to make sure this would actually be possible, but I think it should be.

Comment: Yeah. I think inheriting directly from `Post` is better. That way, I can call `PublishedPost.where(...)` and the flags automatically get set and I dont need to have the extra `decorate` call.

Comment: @Jeff Inheriting from ActiveRecord models affects how they behave (on writes only, I think, which you shouldn't be accessing from a decorator anyways), but more importantly, it's adding another layer of complexity to the models. If you want to abstract the decoration away, you could delegate (either via `method_missing` or explicitly) to the `Post`, though.

Comment: @coreyward The all_posts shouln't be calculated by adding '+' the two arrays together instead of '&'?